# control 'setAttribute' using button event

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to control `setAttribute` using this example, located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530276/transparent-widgets-inside-transparent-frame-pyqt5).  I want to make the background transparent except the button when I click the button. but it's not working. I'm noob, so I do not know what's wrong with this.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MainFrame(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setFixedSize(860, 560)

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("TEST")
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.Btn_clicked)

    def Btn_clicked(self) :
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        print("clicked")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Frame = MainFrame(None)
    Frame.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MainFrame(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setFixedSize(860, 560)

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Make the background transparent ?")
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("""QPushButton { color : #000; font-size: 50px;}""")
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.Btn_clicked)

    def Btn_clicked(self) :
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, False)

        if self.sender().text() == "Make the background transparent ?":
            self.btn.setText("Return the background back.")
            self.btn.setStyleSheet("""QPushButton { color:#fff; background-color:#000;font-size:50px;}""")
            self.setWindowOpacity(0.5)
        else:
            self.btn.setText("Make the background transparent ?")
            self.btn.setStyleSheet("""QPushButton {color: #000; font-size: 50px;}""")
            self.setWindowOpacity(1.0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Frame = MainFrame(None)
    Frame.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make only the background transparent? This also makes the buttons transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821673/turning-wa-translucentbackground-off-stops-window-repainting)!! But unlike that, I don't know exactly why it working.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
class MainFrame(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 400)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("TEST")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)

        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.istransparent = True

    def set_transparency(self) :
        self.btn_bl = not self.btn_bl
        self.set_transparency(self.btn_bl)

    def btn_clicked(self) :

        if not self.istransparent :
            print("transparent activated")
            self.istransparent = not self.istransparent
            self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, self.istransparent)
        else:
            self.istransparent = not self.istransparent
            print("transparent deactivated")
            self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, False)
            self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, self.istransparent)
        self.repaint()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Frame = MainFrame(None)
    Frame.show()
    app.exec_()
```